# How to remove city field from checkout page

Tags: shipping-address, billing-address, checkout-page, magento2.1.0

I have tried to remove city field from checkout page but didn't get success.

Can anyone help to remove city field?

Comment: How have you attempted to remove it? Via code?

Comment: Yes, I have tried via xml file: checkout_index_index.xml

Comment: <item name="city" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                                    </item>

Comment: Did you recompile the xml afterwards?

Comment: It was cache issue. Now, the city field has removed but getting error on place order. Error: Unable to place order.

Comment: Is City set to a required field in the admin?

Comment: Where I need to check it in admin? BTW I have remove required option from "eav_attibute" table

Comment: Is there a logged error or report when it says unable to place order?

Comment: No, I got this error in console.

Comment: @VinodKumar  did you solve your issue?

Comment: @VinodKumar found one good tutorial..  http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/show-hide-fields-ex-street-city-region-country-in-checkout-page   my  issue solved..

Comment: @AskBytes removed city byt using above tutorial but shipping methods not showing(ups)